# How to obtain all ensemble estimates in RandomForestRegressor (scikit-learn)

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, ensemble-learning

I'm trying to fit a random forest regression and I'd like to obtain a distribution of my estimate by looking at the output of every regression tree in the ensemble, returned to me in some sort of list.  In R, providing the `predict.all` option in the `randomForest` predict method does this for me,  Is there any way to do this in the `RandomForestRegressor` class in sklearn?

In 0.13 and above, I see the method apply which returns leaf indices, however I'm not sure how to use these, and I don't see any more clues in the doc for `RandomForestRegressor`.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you upgrade to 0.14?  In 0.14, there is an estimators_ member that gives you access to the individual trees.  See the [RandomForestRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/0.13/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.get_params) docs.

Comment: Ah! I see it.  I guess the way is to just loop over that and call the `predict` method on each estimator.  Fair enough, thanks!

Comment: That attribute has been there from the start, not only in 0.14 - but I guess you already saw that.

Comment: I am not seeing a way to obtain the predictions from individual estimators using the estimators_ member.